# Garbage values when accessing SDL_Rect members from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, sdl

I've been following LazyFoo's [SDL tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) (and also adding my own organization and coding style). When I got to his [animation tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/14_animated_sprites_and_vsync/index.php) I decided to make a separate class to store the variables and methods related to the animation algorithm, rather than having global variables. He uses an array of SDL_Rects to define the boundaries of different sprites on a sprite sheet, so I used an SDL_Rect pointer to store the array in my custom class. When I compiled everything I didn't see an animation, when I compiled the original source code I did. When I started debugging things, I found that when I was rendering the sprites, the rects were actually full of garbage, even though when I initialize them the rects are just fine. I've tried to simplify the problem so many times, but every approach I take to recreate the bug in a simpler environment actually works as expected! So with that in mind I apologize for the large amount of code, because I can't seem to reduce the problem.

texture.h

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_H
#define TEXTURE_H

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <string>

class Animation {
public:
    Animation(SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    ~Animation();

    void load(std::string path, int frames, SDL_Rect* clips),
         free(),
         render(int x, int y),
         next_frame();
private:
    SDL_Renderer* _renderer=NULL;
    SDL_Rect* _clips=NULL;
    SDL_Texture* _texture=NULL;
    int _frame=0, _frames=0, _width=0, _height=0;
};

#endif
```

texture.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include "texture.h"
#include "error.h"

Animation::Animation(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
    _renderer = renderer;
}

Animation::~Animation() {
    free();
    _renderer = NULL;
}

void Animation::load(std::string path, int frames, SDL_Rect* clips) {
    free();
    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;

    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    if (!surface)
        throw ErrorIMG("Could not load image "+path);
    SDL_SetColorKey(surface, SDL_TRUE,
                    SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF));

    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(_renderer, surface);
    if (!texture)
        throw ErrorSDL("Could not create texture from image "+path);

    _width = surface->w;
    _height = surface->h;
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    _frames = frames;
    _clips = clips;
    printf("clips[%d]: w: %d h: %d\n", 0, _clips[0].w, _clips[0].h);
}

void Animation::free() {
    if (_texture) {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(_texture);
        _texture = NULL;
        _clips = NULL;
        _frames = 0;
        _frame = 0;
        _width = 0;
        _height = 0;
    }
}

void Animation::render(int x, int y) {
    SDL_Rect crect = _clips[_frame/4];
    printf("in render (clips[%d]): w: %d, h: %d\n", _frame/4, crect.w, crect.h);
    SDL_Rect render_space = {x, y, crect.w, crect.h};
    SDL_RenderCopy(_renderer, _texture, &_clips[_frame], &render_space);
}

void Animation::next_frame() {
    SDL_Rect crect = _clips[_frame/4];
    printf("in next frame (clips[%d]): w: %d, h: %d\n", _frame/4, crect.w, crect.h);
    ++_frame;
    if (_frame/4 >= _frames)
        _frame = 0;
}
```

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "texture.h"

class Game {
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void main();
private:
    void load_media();

    SDL_Window* _window=NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* _renderer=NULL;
    Animation* _anim=NULL;

    const int SCREEN_WIDTH=640, SCREEN_HEIGHT=480;
};

#endif
```

game.cpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include "game.h"
#include "error.h"

void Game::main() {
    load_media();

    bool has_quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (!has_quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                has_quit = true;

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_renderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
        SDL_RenderClear(_renderer);

        _anim->render(100, 100);
        _anim->next_frame();
        SDL_RenderPresent(_renderer);
    }
}

Game::Game() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
        throw ErrorSDL("SDL could not initialize");

    _window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH,
                               SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!_window)
        throw ErrorSDL("Window could not be created");

    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
    render_flags |= SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC;
    _renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(_window, -1, render_flags);
    if (!_renderer)
        throw ErrorSDL("Renderer could not be created");
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_renderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);

    if (!(IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG) & IMG_INIT_PNG))
        throw ErrorIMG("SDL_image could not initialize");
}

Game::~Game() {
    delete _anim;

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(_renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(_window);
    _renderer = NULL;
    _window = NULL;

    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Game::load_media() {
    const int nclips = 4;
    SDL_Rect clips[nclips];

    for (int i=0; i < nclips; i++) {
        clips[i].x = i*64;
        clips[i].y = 0;
        clips[i].w = 64;
        clips[i].h = 164;
    }

    _anim = new Animation(_renderer);
    _anim->load("sheet.png", nclips, &clips[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing a pointer to a temporary. The `SDL_Rect* clips` pointer that you pass to `Animation::load` is assigned to the member `_clips` used after the function returns. For this to work correctly, the data that is pointed to *needs* to live for as long as the `Animation` class is using it. The problem arises here:

```
void Game::load_media() {
    const int nclips = 4;
    SDL_Rect clips[nclips];
    ...
    _anim->load("sheet.png", nclips, &clips[0]);
}
```

In this piece of code, `clips` is a *local* variable. That means it gets destroyed at the end of `load_media()`, and the memory contents at that location will become garbage.

There are a number of ways you could fix this. A simple one would be to use `std::vector<SDL_Rect>` instead of `SDL_Rect*`. `std::vector` can safely be copied and manages its internals for you. Your new code could look like:

```
class Animation {
    ...
    std::vector<SDL_Rect> _clips;
    ...
}


void Animation::load(std::string path, int frames, std::vector<SDL_Rect> clips) {
    ...
    _clips = clips;
    ...
}

void Game::load_media() {
    const int nclips = 4;
    std::vector<SDL_Rect> clips;
    clips.resize(nclips);
    ...
    _anim->load("sheet.png", nclips, clips);
}
```

And dont forget to `#include <vector>`. Documentation for `std::vector` is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Note that `std::vector` has a `size()` method that can probably replace `frames` everywhere it appears.

Comment: So, what I thought I understood when I was writing the code, was that I was creating data, then saving a pointer to the data so it doesn't get lost. However because the data was created in the stack, it gets destroyed once the stack level is destroyed, and the pointer now points to nothing? I'll try using vector, but to clear up more possible confusion: if I originally created a pointer, then initialized the array through the pointer, would the same thing happen?

Comment: @JosieThompson if you heap-allocate the pointer array using `new SDL_Rect[nclips]`, then the data will live beyond the end of the function, but you'll be responsible to `delete[]` it when you're done.

Comment: @JosieThompson Also note that `std::vector` does that work for you without you needing to think about it.

Comment: I just stumbled across this: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f43-never-directly-or-indirectly-return-a-pointer-or-a-reference-to-a-local-object, and it clearly explains my problem. Can I suggest you include it in your answer: on the rare chance that someone with my same problem find this post, I think it would definitely provide additional clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The stack-allocated `Game::load_media()::clips` array disappears when it goes out of scope.  Make a copy in `Animation::load()` instead of only storing a pointer.

Comment: That's what I was thinking was happening, but when I tried to confirm it in a simpler environment it worked as expected... maybe I replicated it wrong?

Comment: @JosieThompson reading from destroyed memory is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). _Anything_ can happen, whether surprising or not.